# phpmyadmin ошибка в доступе отказано

Tags: phpmyadmin

Сегодня я скачал локальный сервер mamp. Но когда я хотел войти в phpmyadmin вышла ошибка что в доступе отказано. Помогите решить эту проблему.

Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Скачал и установил openserver.